# How to upload assets to s3 from webpack

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, webpack

I'm new to webpack.I want to upload my minified js file to s3 using webpack.I used follwing code in webpack.config.js file.

```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
var S3Plugin = require('webpack-s3-plugin');

     module.exports = {
         entry: './src/app.js',
         output: {
             path: './bin',
             filename: 'app.bundle.js'
         },
          plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                },
            }),
            new S3Plugin({
          // Only upload css and js
          include: /.*\.(css|js)/,
          // s3Options are required
          s3Options: {
            accessKeyId: 'key',
            secretAccessKey: 'key',
            region: 'Oregon',
            signatureVersion: 'v4',
     /*       s3BucketEndpoint: true,*/
            endpoint: "endpoint"
          },
          s3UploadOptions: {
            Bucket: 'bucketname'
          }
        })
        ]
     };
```

but i'm getting following error in webpack **ERROR in S3Plugin: Error: Non-file stream objects are not supported with SigV4 in AWS.S3** how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the signatureVersion to v3:

```
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v3',
    region: 'eu-central-1'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this s3-plugin-webpack fork:

npm install git+https://github.com/fabianfett/s3-plugin-webpack.git

as suggested by the author:
https://github.com/MikaAK/s3-plugin-webpack/issues/43#issuecomment-238854713

Tested with 'eu-central-1' region. Should work using 'us-west-2' (Oregon) too.